# Html literals in MVC3 model code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a RegisterModel view model I use for my new account registration page.  Depending on the status of a registration task, the model has a relevant text message to display for the user, e.g. "Waiting for email confirmation" etc.

I currently populate this string property in the manner below, but couldn't help wondering about mixing markup and content like I do with the `<p>` tags.  Is there a better or more accepted way of doing this, besides having multiple partial views with actual HTML literals instead of model properties?

```
RegisterMessage = "<p>Please use the form below to create a new account.</p>";
RegisterMessage = string.Format("<p>Passwords are required to be a minimum of {0} characters in length.</p>", _membershipService.MinRequiredPasswordLength);
```

**EDIT:**  I have just noticed that the `<p>` tags are rendering literally, but I doubt that issue falls under the same question.

Comment: I think you're missing the example you intended to provide.

Comment: I think you should describe what you mean by better.

Comment: @tvanfosson I have added my forgotten sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a status property in the view model and in the view:

```
@if (Model.Status == Status.StatusA)
{
    <div>Message 1</div>
} 
else if (Model.Status == Status.StatusB)
{
    <div>Message 2</div>
}
```

and if you wanted to render HTML literals in Razor without encoding them:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.RegisterMessage)
```

But the example you have shown seems like a validation error message which could also be stored in a resources file.

Comment: I get a parser error using the ':' notation: *":" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.*

Comment: @ProfK, that's because `@:` is inappropriate in this case. I have removed it from my answer. When you use `@:Model.RegisterMessage` it will render `Model.RegisterMessage` in the resulting HTML instead of evaluating the property. So you should use `@Html.Raw(Model.RegisterMessage)` if you want to render the value unencoded.

Comment: Thanks @Darin, I got Raw as a working alternative from your original answer anyway.